# What is the simplest way to write the output of a Java document to a .rtf file?

Tags: java, output, rtf

I am wondering what the easiest way to write the output (last line of non-commented code below) to a .rtf file so that I can format some aspects with italics as well as keep a continuous, copy and paste-able, list of all my citations. Is there a way to do what I want that is simple? I am a beginner at Java and don't want anything *too* complicated to deal with.

```
/* (c) Tyler Holley January, 2018
 * CitationGenerator Version 0.2
 * 
 * User inputs academic source information and gets a proper citation back ready for copy and pasting into a Works Cited page.
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

class CitationGenerator {
    public static String bookFormat(String author, String title, String publisher, int pubDate) {
        // 
        String bFormat = author + ". " + title + ", " + publisher + ", " + pubDate + ".";

        return bFormat;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String error1 = "ERROR: INVALID INPUT."; // Catchall error
        String errorN = "ERROR: No other formats are currently supported in this version."; // Filler error while WIP

        System.out.println("Welcome to CitationGenerator v0.1!");
        System.out.print("What format is your citation in? MLA/APA/Chicago: "); // Add APA/Chicago support
        String format = in.next();

        if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("MLA")) { // equalsIgnoreCase ignores case inputted so MLA, mLa, mla, etc. are all valid
            System.out.print("\nIs your source a book, website, or other? ");
            String sourceType = in.next();
            // Try and figure out how to clear the console after the user inputs sourceType 

            if (sourceType.equalsIgnoreCase("book")) {
                System.out.print("\nAuthor's First Name: ");
                String fName = in.next();

                System.out.print("Author's Last Name: ");
                String lName = in.next();
                in.nextLine();

                System.out.print("\nBook Title: ");
                String title = in.nextLine();

                System.out.print("\nPublisher Name: ");
                String publisher = in.nextLine();

                System.out.print("\nPublication Date: ");
                int pubDate = in.nextInt();

                String author = lName + ", " + fName; // Converts fName and lName to one concatonated String

                System.out.println("\n\nHere is your citation! Don't forget to italicize the title!\n");
                // Try to automatically italicize text when converting program to a .rtf
                System.out.println(bookFormat(author, title, publisher, pubDate));


                // GOAL: Alternate to the println below :
                //System.out.println("\n\nYour citation is ready, would you like to save it to a/the .rtf document? y/n");
                // This would branch into an if/else statement to print either to a document or continue to terminal output.
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: have you done any research into this on your own?

Comment: Yes I have but all of the things I am finding are very complicated. I was looking for the simplest method possible.

Comment: I did something similar once. I ended up reading the RTF specification from Microsoft. Then I took the first and the last part of an existing RTF document and writing RTF codes from my Java program in the middle. The RTF format is textual, so you may study the inside of existing documents to understand the specification better.

Comment: If what you really need is to generate text in italics, it’s probably simpler to generate HTML with the <em> or <i> tag around the text.

Comment: For my purposes, it needs to be a readable and directly editable file either in .rtf, .docx, or .pages; I chose .rtf and can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Did you try what I wrote below?

Comment: Could you please explain how what you wrote works? What does the `DataOutputStream dos;` line work?

Answer (score -2):

Pretty similar to writing to any file:

```
DataOutputStream dos;
File file = new File("\\your\\file\\path\\file.rtf");
try {
    dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    dos.writeBytes(bookFormat(author, title, publisher, pubDate));
    dos.close();
catch( //IOexception or similar etc
```

**Output:**

> surname, firstname. booktitle, bookpublisher, 1234.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This writes the desired output to a .rtf file. Is it because OP provided no effort? Shouldn't we help sometimes anyway? Maybe if we're in a good mood?

Comment: Does this make an actual RTF file?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes - `Type: Rich Text Format` - or am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: As far as I am aware, rtf is a markup format. Just adding an extension to a text file does not make it rtf.

Comment: Also, this is an unnecessarily complicated way of writing strings to a file.

Comment: Do you have a more simple way?

Comment: It’s hardly complicated. And isn’t rtf just a file extension, which is what this saves it as?

Comment: @notyou. Windows would call it an xml file if you added .xml to the end of the file name. That doesn't mean anything. An actual rtf file's contents have to follow a particular spec. You can look it up on the Microsoft website. I don't have a link offhand.